# What is factorygirl used for? setting up objects for you?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Is factorygirl's purpose in a testing environment to setup the objects used in the test?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, yes.

Although it does a little more then that. It allows you to create model objects and their dependencies and it gives you the option to persist those objects to your database or not as well as create stub objects.

In addition, it makes it a lot more obvious what model objects you are working with in your tests. Fixtures tend to hide this information and you have no choice but to persist those objects.